# If $a^{b^2}=b^a$ find $a,b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $$a^{b^2}=b^a$$ then find all possible $a,b$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{I^+}$.

I found a trivial solution $a=b=1$ but could not found more. I tried to use log and ended up here$:$ $$\frac{\operatorname{log}a}{\operatorname{log}b}=\frac{a}{b^2}$$ Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I checked this problem on wolfram alpha and even it is not showing all solutions.

Comment: Looking at a graph on Desmos suggests $a=b^3$ to be the set of integer solutions. This falls apart for $a>3$ so nevermind.

Comment: Yeah, there are two more solutions in which one is satisfying this condition but the other doesn't

Comment: And can't we do it without any software's help

Comment: Typing this into [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E%7Bb%5E2%7D%3Db%5Ea%24&p=1) (math-aware search engine), leads to duplicates: [Find all positive integers satisfying $a^{b^2}=b^a$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3504067/318073), [What are the integer solutions to $a^{b^2} = b^a$ with $a, b \ge 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3611719/318073), ... and that this is IMO1997, problem 5., their solution is linked on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1995239p13920125).

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gcd(b^2,a)=d$, so that $b^2=dm, a=dn$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$.
We have $a^m = b^n$, so there must be integer u so that $a=u^n, b=u^m$.

u=1 is a special solution which results in a=b=1.

If $u\gt 1$, we have $b^2=u^{2m}$ so that $d=\gcd(b^2,a)=\gcd(u^{2m},u^n)=u^{\min\{2m,n\}}=\min\{b^2,a\}$.
So either m=1 or n=1.

If m=1, we have $d=b^2=u^2, a=u^n=dn=u^2n$ , so $u^{n-2}=n$. Since $u\ge 2$ and it is easy to show that for any $n\ge 5$, we have $u^{n-2}\ge 2^{n-2}\gt n$,
If n=2, no solution.

If n=3, we have $u=n=3, a=27,b=3$.

If n=4, we have $u^2=4, u=2, a=16,b=2$
the only solution is u=2&n=4, which results in a=16,b=2.

If n=1, we have $a=d=u, b^2=dm=um=u^{2m}$, so we have $m=u^{2m-1}\ge 2^{2m-1}$. It is easy to show that $2^{2m-1} \gt m$ for any $m\ge 2$.

So the all solutions are a=1&b=1, a=27&b=3, a=16&b=2

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a proof*

Using algebra
$$a^{b^2}=b^a \implies a=-\frac{b^2}{\log (b)}\,W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (b)}{b^2}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. This makes inspection quite easy. Running for $1 \leq b \leq 10^6$ (which coreesponds to $1 \leq a \lt 2.03\cdots\times 10^{18}$), the only pairs are $(1,1),(16,2),(27,3)$.